# Use AWS SDK to programmatically schedule and remove Eventbridge events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have a serverless infrastructure that has a front-end web app.  In this front-end, users can select specific times of day for taskX to occur.

I know (and have) set up events to occur on a recurring schedule with a manually-created (with [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/)) cron-based trigger.  It's my understanding I could use a cron to trigger at specific times as explained here: [How to trigger a Lambda function at specific time in AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538170/how-to-trigger-a-lambda-function-at-specific-time-in-aws) and here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html ...

...however, I don't know how I would *programmatically* create (and also remove) these events using the AWS SDK.  (also noting I might have thousands of said events -  [Perhaps eventbridge isn't the right tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-quota.html)?)

Suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutRule.html

Comment: ugh... I searched for that for quite a while. No idea why I couldn't find it!  Thanks!

Comment: ALso - what language are you using. For example, if you want to use AWS SDK for Java, see https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/eventbridge

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question correctly, you need to set up a one-time schedule. Recently(10-Nov-2022) AWS launched a new service called [EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html) and it supports a One-time schedule. I already added an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74425228/6194097), please have a look. If not comment below, I might think I can help you.