# AWS Lambda Function throws Read timed out. (read timeout=60) when invoking

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I created a Lambda function on AWS Lambda from an AWS C9 environment. The function runs well from local, but after deploying it, it times out on remote.

This is the error:

```
Error: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='lambda.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)

at convertStderrToError (https://d373lap04ubgnu.cloudfront.net/c9-2108b841e591-ide/build/configs/ide/@aws/cloud9/configs/ide/environment-default.js:9982:33)
at exports.EventEmitter.<anonymous> (https://d373lap04ubgnu.cloudfront.net/c9-2108b841e591-ide/build/configs/ide/@aws/cloud9/configs/ide/environment-default.js:9974:70)
at exports.EventEmitter.EventEmitter.emit (https://d373lap04ubgnu.cloudfront.net/c9-2108b841e591-ide/build/configs/ide/@aws/cloud9/configs/ide/environment-default.js:19:23)
at Consumer.onExit (https://d373lap04ubgnu.cloudfront.net/c9-2108b841e591-ide/build/configs/ide/@aws/cloud9/configs/ide/environment-default.js:48909:80)
at Consumer.<anonymous> (https://d373lap04ubgnu.cloudfront.net/c9-2108b841e591-ide/build/configs/ide/@aws/cloud9/configs/ide/environment-default.js:48698:4)
at Consumer.Agent._onMessage (https://d373lap04ubgnu.cloudfront.net/c9-2108b841e591-ide/build/configs/ide/@aws/cloud9/configs/ide/environment-default.js:48778:4)
at EngineIoTransport.EventEmitter.emit (https://d373lap04ubgnu.cloudfront.net/c9-2108b841e591-ide/build/configs/ide/@aws/cloud9/configs/ide/environment-default.js:48538:16)
at module.exports.onMessage (https://d373lap04ubgnu.cloudfront.net/c9-2108b841e591-ide/build/configs/ide/@aws/cloud9/configs/ide/environment-default.js:48838:6)
at module.exports.EventEmitter.emit (https://d373lap04ubgnu.cloudfront.net/c9-2108b841e591-ide/build/configs/ide/@aws/cloud9/configs/ide/environment-default.js:18:23)
at module.exports.ReliableSocket.onMessage (https://d373lap04ubgnu.cloudfront.net/c9-2108b841e591-ide/build/configs/ide/@aws/cloud9/configs/ide/environment-default.js:49026:76)
```

I can see that the problem is not in my code, because the function doesn't even get called. Any tips?

Comment: Is your function launching that exception or is it some other piece of code?

Comment: Is this deployed in a VPC?

Comment: Sorry, No, it's not on a VPC. And the function trows the exception (or AWS lambda itself, not sure). My code doesn't even get called.

Comment: Can you please post what language your code is written and when you say "it times out on remote" what does that mean. Also please do have a look at your cloudwatch logs for the lambda

Comment: It is most likely a permission/network issue. See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019617/can-aws-lambdas-receive-inbound-tcp-connections