# Dynamodb scan pagination is not working as I'm expecting

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

[CloudWatch Log of Lambda Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYmfS.jpg)

I'm using the below code to scan with pagination a dynamodb table to pull 5 records from a maximum of 20 records. When I invoke the api through postman GET method it is pulling the same 5 records each time. Does it mean that my lambda code doesn't work properly or do I need to customize my API call in postman?

```
import boto3
import os
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='ap-southeast-1')
    pagination_config={
            "MaxItems":20, 
            "PageSize": 5
            }
    
    paginator = client.get_paginator('scan')
    response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
        TableName="Users", 
        PaginationConfig=pagination_config
    )
    for page in response_iterator:
        Items = page['Items']
        print(Items)
        print("--------------------------")

    from botocore.paginate import TokenEncoder
    encoder = TokenEncoder()
    for page in response_iterator:
        if "LastEvaluatedKey" in page:
            encoded_token = encoder.encode({"ExclusiveStartKey": page["LastEvaluatedKey"]})
            pagination_config = {
                    "MaxItems": 20,
                    "PageSize": 5,
                    "StartingToken": encoded_token
                    }
            Items = page['Items']
            
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {},
        'body': json.dumps(Items)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When paginating you need to start with the `LastEvaluatedKey` of your previous call. In the posted code the same `LastEvaluatedKey` is being used over and over which will not allow for pagination and will produce the same result.
here is an example that you can run locally

```
import os
import json
from botocore.paginate import TokenEncoder

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    key= event['key'] 
    client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='ap-southeast-1')
    
    if not key:
        pagination_config = {"MaxItems": 20, "PageSize": 5}
    else:
        encoder = TokenEncoder()
        encoded_token=encoder.encode({'ExclusiveStartKey':  {'id': {'S': key}}})
        pagination_config = {"MaxItems": 20, "PageSize": 5, "StartingToken":  encoded_token } 
        

    paginator = client.get_paginator('scan')
    response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
        TableName="Users", 
        PaginationConfig=pagination_config
    )
            
    for page in response_iterator:
        Items = page['Items']
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {},
        'body': json.dumps(Items),
        'LastEvaluatedKey' : page["LastEvaluatedKey"]
    }
```

in the response the last evaluated key will look like:

```
"LastEvaluatedKey": {"id": {"S": "???????"}}}"
```

be sure to use it for your next pagination.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I still can't figure out how to call my API with your given code to paginate into my client (Postman). I want to accomplish something like following. There will be a list API where I can see all the entries. Let's assume that my dynamodb table has 200 records. The list API has to be paginated, where I can tell the number of entries I want to get. If the number is not defined then 5 entries will be on the list. I'm trying to learn this things. Is it possible to accomplish this kind of thing using dynamodb pagination feature?

Comment: 1. I have revised my answer to read the key from the event object. 2. To send a request from postman/curl you need to setup gateway, here is a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877220/invoke-a-aws-lambda-function-by-a-http-request

Comment: [ERROR] TypeError: lambda_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'

Comment: data= lambda_handler("KeyFromLastCall")

Comment: Thanks again. Maybe being so noob as I'm almost new to the development world. In fact I have already setup api gateway. I tried with your revised code to invoke my api gateway through Postman. It is giving application error. Any thought regarding this error?

Comment: try again , I removed the code that is meant for testing. Now the code has only the lambda function.

Comment: Fixed import issue of boto3. Now giving this error. [ERROR] KeyError: 'key'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 7, in lambda_handler
    key= event['key']

Comment: in the body of the message your sending via postman/curl you need to provide a key , something like {"key": ""}

Comment: I tried with {"key": ""} and {"key": "6d9079ac-5414-4299-a2ff-996c5e621d81"} but both request sends me 403 error to the client. Lambda gives [ERROR] KeyError: 'key'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 7, in lambda_handler
    key= event['key']

Comment: My dynamodb schema only has primary key which is 'id' as string. my first record is {
  "datetime": "12/21/2020, 20:45:27",
  "id": "6d9079ac-5414-4299-a2ff-996c5e621d81",
  "username": "User 1"
}

Comment: try again I corrected the key extraction. Be sure to have a key item: {"key": ""}